# Error Resolving User Permissions + Zsh Command Not Found

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, zsh, path

This is the list of user permissions after logging them to the terminal:

```
➜  ~  ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/manpath
drwxr-xr-x    33 root  wheel   1190 Nov 14 08:49 /
drwxr-xr-x@   11 root  wheel    374 Nov  7 09:12 /usr
drwxr-xr-x  1055 root  wheel  35870 Nov 12 11:34 /usr/bin
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root  wheel      3 Nov  5 18:13 /usr/bin/manpath -> man
```

And this is the error I receive when trying to update the permissions:

```
➜  ~  chmod 755 / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/*
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/bin/apropos: Operation not permitted
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/bin/at: Operation not permitted
```

This all began as an effort to debug the following zsh error:

```
zsh: command not found
```

I have tried resetting my $PATH variable to no avail. I've uninstalled and reinstalled zsh, run brew doctor, reinstalled node, etc. and am unsure where to proceed from here. The problems I am trying to fix are two-fold:

1. fix the PATH so that I can use commands (e.g.: ionic) from the
   terminal
2. fix the permissions so I don't encounter any further
   errors as I troubleshoot going forward

Can anyone offer guidance? Been trying to debug this for hours.

This my current PATH:

```
➜  ~  echo $PATH                               
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: (1) Why are you trying to change the mode of these directories to what they already are?  (2) How do you get that `zsh: command not found` error message?  As a result of logging in, getting a login shell (that isn't `zsh`), and typing `zsh`(Enter)?  If so, that isn't a "zsh error"; it's an error from your shell.  (3) To solve your problem, figure out where `zsh` is.  Try `find / -type f -name zsh -print`.  (4) Just for fun, do `ls -ld /usr/bin/apropos /usr/bin/at`.

Comment: **1)** I'm pretty new to mac coming from 25+ years on Windows, and just trying to troubleshoot based off of a Stack Overflow post that recommended my zsh error might be related to permissions
**2)** the `zsh: command not found` error happens whenever I try to run something with its terminal shortcut e.g.: ionic, etc.

I just ran the find / command you posted and got : 
`find / -type f -name zsh -print
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied`, among many others. 

Zsh is located in my `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.1.1/bin/zsh` from what I can tell, since I installed it with Homebrew.